# Java how to replace backslash?

Tags: java, regex

In java, I have a file path, like 'C:\A\B\C', I want it changed to ''C:/A/B/C'. how to replace the backslashes?

Comment: By the way, "\" is a backslash and not a slash. https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Backslash

Comment: You have no slashes in that string.  You have backslashes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
    String text = "C:\\A\\B\\C";
    String newString = text.replace("\\", "/");
    System.out.println(newString);
```

Answer (score 11):

Since you asked for a regular expression, you'll have to escape the '\' character several times:

```
String path = "c:\\A\\B\\C";
System.out.println(path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/"));
```

Comment: +1 for noticing (and being responsive to) the "regex" tag, even though the problem doesn't actually need regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the String.replace method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String foo = "C:\\foo\\bar";
    String newfoo = foo.replace("\\", "/");
    System.out.println(newfoo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace all occurrences of a given character :

```
String result = candidate.replace( '\\', '/' );
```

Regards,
Cyril

Comment: This won't compile. You need `'\\'` instead of `'\'`.

Comment: essentially, '\\' is a escaped '\' char

Comment: @Cyril - I checked and your answer is correct! Sorry man. I've deleted my stupid comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
String oldPath = "C:\\A\\B\\C";
String newPath = oldPath.replace('\\', '/');
```