# replace "\" with "" in java

Tags: java, regex, string

my question is quite simple:

how to replace **"\"** with **""** ???

I tried this:

```
str.replaceAll("\\", "");
```

but I get en exception

```
08-04 01:14:50.146: I/LOG(7091): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_BAD_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE near index 1:
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace String with another in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java how to replace slash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756748/java-how-to-replace-slash)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's simpler if you *don't* use `replaceAll` (which takes a regex) for this - just use `replace` (which takes a plain string). Don't use the regular expression form unless you really *need* regexes. It just makes things more complicated.

Don't forget that just *calling* `replace` or `replaceAll` is pointless as strings are immutable - you need to use the return result:

```
String replaced = str.replace("\\", "");
```

Comment: I like the fact that you look at the bigger picture.

Answer (score 11):

`\\` is `\` after string escaping, which is also an escape character in regex try

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

(don't forget to assign the result)

Also, if you use some string as an input where a regular expression is expected, it is safer IMO to use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\"), "");
```

Answer (score 10):

You should try this:

```
str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

The `\` has to be escaped in regex => you should write `\\`, and each `\` has to be escaped in java => thats why we have the 4 `\`

Comment: While I think you are correct, you should explain why as well.

Comment: java escapes \ and regex needs to escape \ so 2X2 = 4 :)