# Java replace " with \"

Tags: java, string, replace

I am trying to replace string containing " with \" , below is the program I tried

```
    String s="\"/test /string\"";
    s = s.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
    System.out.println(s);
```

But I get the same output as the string "/test /string". Why is my replace function is not working. If I do

```
   s = s.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```

then I get the output I want \"/test /string\" . Why is the former dint work , even though in code I am trying to replace " with \"

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace String with another in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java how to replace slash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756748/java-how-to-replace-slash)

Answer (score 10):

You're using [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), which takes a regular expression as its inputs, including the replacement. As documented in [`Match.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29):

> Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string.

You're really just trying to do a straight replace with no regexes involved, so use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead:

```
s = s.replace("\"", "\\\"");
```